# How to install Windows 7 from SSD?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, grub

I need to install Windows 7 from SDD (since I don't have optical drive nor a USB stick). I currently have Linux Mint 18. What I already have done:

1. Created 7000 MB NTFS partition.
2. Copied there 4.7 GB of Windows 7 installation files from the .iso image.
3. Ran `sudo update-grub` in a terminal window.

Now in Grub menu, I see Windows option, but after choosing it I get an error similar to the screenshot below (“Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause…”), except the error is "0xc000000**e**" (not "f").

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you copy files or burn the iso?

Comment: @fixer1234 I copied files to partition, I didn't burn .iso.

Comment: What Ramhound said.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm doing wrong?

You won't be able to install Windows using the method you are using.  There are numerous things that the installation environment does, including extracting compressed files, you CANNOT recreate what the Windows installation environment does yourself manually.

You need to use an optical drive or a bootable mass storage device in order to install Windows

Comment: @Cint - Since you did not specifically indicate this level of detail in your question, it's possible what you are trying to do is make your internal disk bootable, so you can install it to another internal disk.  If that is the case you forgot to make the disk bootable.  [Install Windows 10/8.1 From External Hard Drive](http://www.intowindows.com/install-windows-8-from-external-hard-drive/).  I still suggest just creating a bootable optical or mass storage device instead.

Comment: I cannot find any command that exists for Linux that would make a partition bootable that is compatible with the Windows environment.  So I stand by my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use [WinToUSB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/) to write your Windows ISO to the SSD properly. It should then be able to boot up fine.

Very simple to use, simply launch the software, point it to your ISO Image, select the destination drive and off you go. You'll obviously need a different computer to do this on with your newly formatted NTFS SSD mounted.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT5Nvsr1Sww) as well.